# Unable to perform client reset after doing schema changes using given sample in mongo db for realm android java sdk

Tags: java, android, mongodb, kotlin, realm

Unable to perform client reset after doing schema changes using given sample in mongo db for realm android java sdk. But i was able to perform client reset after toggling sync in atlas.  The problem lies client reset not happening after breaking schema changes. Even I fixed schema.
This is the given sample in Mongo reference. And is there any process where we could now client reset triggers??

```
String appID = YOUR_APP_ID; // replace this with your App ID
App app = null;
AtomicReference<App> globalApp = new AtomicReference<>(app);
// accessing the app from within the lambda below requires an effectively final object
app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder(appID)
        .defaultSyncClientResetStrategy(new DiscardUnsyncedChangesStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onBeforeReset(Realm realm) {
                Log.w("EXAMPLE", "Beginning client reset for " + realm.getPath());
            }
            @Override
            public void onAfterReset(Realm before, Realm after) {
                Log.w("EXAMPLE", "Finished client reset for " + before.getPath());
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(SyncSession session, ClientResetRequiredError error) {
                Log.e("EXAMPLE", "Couldn't handle the client reset automatically." +
                        " Falling back to manual client reset execution: "
                        + error.getErrorMessage());
                // close all instances of your realm -- this application only uses one
                globalRealm.close();
                try {
                    Log.w("EXAMPLE", "About to execute the client reset.");
                    // execute the client reset, moving the current realm to a backup file
                    error.executeClientReset();
                    Log.w("EXAMPLE", "Executed the client reset.");
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e("EXAMPLE", "Failed to execute the client reset: " + e.getMessage());
                    // The client reset can only proceed if there are no open realms.
                    // if execution failed, ask the user to restart the app, and we'll client reset
                    // when we first open the app connection.
                    AlertDialog restartDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setMessage("Sync error. Restart the application to resume sync.")
                            .setTitle("Restart to Continue")
                            .create();
                    restartDialog.show();
                }
                // open a new instance of the realm. This initializes a new file for the new realm
                // and downloads the backend state. Do this in a background thread so we can wait
                // for server changes to fully download.
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    Realm newRealm = Realm.getInstance(globalConfig);
                    // ensure that the backend state is fully downloaded before proceeding
                    try {
                        globalApp.get().getSync().getSession(globalConfig).downloadAllServerChanges(10000,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.w("EXAMPLE",
                            "Downloaded server changes for a fresh instance of the realm.");
                    newRealm.close();
                });
                // execute the recovery logic on a background thread
                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })
        .build());
globalApp.set(app);
```

Comment: Question: Does it work if you delete all local data on client reset and allow the app to re-sync to the server? (assuming the schema matches the schema on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found which was nowhere mentioned. As I'm new to mongo db I had to go through lots of documentation reading but nowhere I found that when client reset occurs or if there is any issue with sync we must check logs in mongo db atlas.

Logs give us the exact reason why syncing has stopped and we can fix it accordingly. After fixing my client reset code started working properly.
[image]

Hope it helps.